# Here i have cshtml and js ajax .. I have two sites ..First site opened the popup modal ...Another site not opened the popup modal

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api, bootstrap-4

Here i have cshtml and js ajax .. I have two sites ..First site opened the popup modal ...Another site  not opened the popup modal why?.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="addNote" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-large">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Notes for <span id="noteTitle">@Model.TitleName</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

```
 <span class="float-right btn" id="btnnote" onclick="openAuthNotePopup();" style="padding:0px;"><img title="Add Note" width="25" height="25" alt="Add Note" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/sticky-note2.png")' /></span>   


 function openAuthNotePopup() {
    var memberNotesUrl = '@(Url.Action("CreateNote", "Notes", new { area = AreaName.Notes}))' + "?modulePageID=" + '@((int)Enums.Page.NoteAuthorizations)' + "&id=" + '@(Model.AuthorizationID)' + "&memberOrProviderID=" + '@(Model.MemberID)' + "&titleName=" + '@(titleName)';
    $("#divNotes").html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: memberNotesUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divNotes").html(data);
            $('#addNote').modal()
            $('#addNote').modal('show')
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console of second site.

Comment: Nope brother...